# How to sum one column value to other column value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to Tables T1 and T2

T1

```
Id name open   receive close
1  jon  5000    4000   1000
2  jim  6000    5000   1000
```

T2

```
Id name receive
1  jon   500
2  jim   700
```

I Want like this (T1 receive + T2 receive) Result

```
Id name  open   receive close
1  jon   5000   4500    500
2  jim   6000   5700    300
```

I'm using Sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Tim Biegeleisen's answer is more correct.

You need to do a join on the two tables like that:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.open, T1.receive+T2.receive, T1.close
FROM T1 JOIN T2 USING (id);
```

**Edit**: If you want to update `T1`, you can do it like that:

```
UPDATE T1
SET receive=receive+coalesce((SELECT receive FROM T2 WHERE T1.id=T2.id),0);
```

Comment: can u tell answer with update or insert query if possible?

Comment: @MuhammadKashifSaeed What do you mean? Do you want to update the `T1` table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right, good catch. I didn't notice that as it wan't explicitly mentioned in the requirements. +1

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm more right but I also upvoted you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT T1.name,
       T1.open,
       T1.receive + COALESCE(T2.receive, 0) AS receive,
       T1.close - COALESCE(T2.receive, 0)   AS close
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
    ON T1.Id = T2.Id
```

If you want to `UPDATE` the first table, you can try this:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.recieve = T1.recieve +
    (SELECT COALESCE(T2.recieve, 0) FROM T2 WHERE T2.Id = T1.Id),
    T1.close = T1.close -
    (SELECT COALESCE(T2.recieve, 0) FROM T2 WHERE T2.Id = T1.Id)
```

Comment: Thanks, u also update the close column as per my expectations.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one row per `id`, then you can do:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.open, (t1.receive + t2.receive), t1.close
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

I could speculate that `t2` actually has multiple rows for a given id or missing rows.  This would suggest:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.open, (t1.receive + t2.receive), t1.close
from t1 left join
     (select t2.id, sum(t2.receive) as receive
      from t2
      group by t2.id
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```