# How to update tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two Tables T1 and T2

T1

```
Id name open   receive close
1  jon  5000    0      5000
2  jim  6000    0      6000
3  ben  9000    0      9000
```

T2

```
Id name receive
1  jon   500
3  ben   200
2  jim   700
1  jon   500
2  jim   700
3  ben   100
```

First thing that I want how to order the T2 with update query.

```
Id name receive
1  jon   500
1  jon   500
2  jim   700
2  jim   700
3  ben   100
3  ben   200
```

After that, I Want update T1 like this

```
Id name  open   receive close
1  jon   5000   1000    4000
2  jim   6000   1400    4600
3  ben   9000    300    8700
```

I'm using Sqlite

Comment: Didn't you basically ask the same question yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367981/how-to-sum-one-column-value-to-other-column-value

Comment: This question is different

Answer (score 2):

First question

```
select * from T2 order by Id, receive
```

Second question

```
update T1
set T1.receive = T2.receive,
    T1.close = T1.open - T2.receive
from T1
inner join (select Id, sum(receive) receive from T2 group by Id) T2
    on T1.Id = T2.Id
```

Comment: is it possible when the new entry entered in T2 it also update the T2 by order

Comment: What you mean update T2? You mean the first SQL? it only retrieve data from T2; For 2nd SQL, it will update T1 when you execute the SQL only, if you want to do that automatically, you need a trigger

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why update the table because you can use  either select order by clause like this

```
Select * from #T2
Order By Id ASC
```

Now for the third Screen shot you can use this

```
Update t1
Set  T1.[receive] = T2.[receive]
,T1.[close] = T1.[open]- T2.[receive]
from #T1 t1
inner join(
Select t2.ID,t2.name,Sum(t2.[receive]) AS [receive] from #T2
Group By ID,name) T2
on T1.Id=T2.Id
```

If have used the folleoinf example

```
Create Table #T1 (Id int,name nvarchar(255), [open] int,[receive] int, [close] int)

Insert into #T1 Values
(1,'jon',5000,0,5000),
(2,'jim',6000,0,6000),
(3,'ben',9000,0,9000)


Create Table #T2(Id int,name nvarchar(255),[receive] int)

 Insert into #T2 Values
(1,'jon',500),
(3,'ben',200),
(2,'jim',700),
(1,'jon',500),
 (2,'jim',700),
  (3,'ben',100)
```